# Error in downloading large file (11 MB) from Azure Blob in Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am developing a project in **Blazor Server** in **.NET 6**. I have an upload and download functionalites in **Azure Container**. When I am trying to download a large file (11 MB) it takes long time to process and finally it shows error in the browser console.

The steps I followed, first I am getting the file from Azure Blob and then I am reading the stream. Then I wrote some code in JavaScript to read that stream and download the file trhough the browser.

**Here is the C# code:**

```
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "uploadfiles");

try
{
    BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
    {
        Stream blobContent = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync();

        var content = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
        string contentType = content.Value.Details.ContentType;
        
        using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: blobContent);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", blobName, streamRef);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**Here is the JavaScript code:**

```
window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
    const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

But I can downlaod samll sized file. But when try to download large file for example with **11 MB in size** I get the below exception throws:

> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.d__16`1.MoveNext()    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()    at
> BlazorApp4.Pages.Index.d__16.MoveNext() in
> C:\Users\source\repos\BlazorApp4\BlazorApp4\Pages\Index.razor.cs:line
> 153

And here is the **Browser console error**:
[image]

Comment: Did you use Azure SignalR ? Because the small file is downloaded successfully, the download method is no problem. At present, because files larger than 11M may cause timeouts, you need to confirm whether you use SignalR?

Comment: No I didn't use SignlarR

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code so that you can easily reproduce the issue. Pls hide the connectionstring of azure storage.

Comment: Not having Azure SignalR Service in your project does not mean you are not using SignalR. Blazor Server uses SignalR anyway. [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server)